# Why is this jQuery Validation not working on IE 7/8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm encountering a small problem with a client-side validation script which works on all browsers including IE 9 / 10, but is giving me headaches on IE 7 and IE 8.

The page with the form which needs this validation can be accesed [over here](http://www.anuntulliber.ro/adaugare_anunt) and someone must definetly take a look in order to give a good answer.

And here's the validation script I use for the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
  jQuery("#adaugareanunt").submit(function(event){  

    errornotice = jQuery("#eroareadaugare");
    emptyerror = "Necompletat";
    emailerror = "Email incorect";
    email = jQuery('#contactEmail');
    descriere = jQuery('#descriptionro_RO');

    jQuery('#adaugareanunt input[type="text"]').each(function(){

        if ((jQuery(this).val() == "") || (jQuery(this).val() == emptyerror)) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("campuri-necesare");
            jQuery(this).val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("campuri-necesare");
        }

    });

    jQuery('#adaugareanunt select').each(function(){

        if ((jQuery(this).val() == "")) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("campuri-necesare");
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("campuri-necesare");
        }

    });

    if(descriere.val() == "" || descriere.val() == emptyerror) {
            descriere.addClass("campuri-necesare");
            descriere.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
    } else { 
            descriere.removeClass("campuri-necesare");
    }

    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("campuri-necesare");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }





    if (jQuery(":input").hasClass("campuri-necesare")) {
        return false;
    } 
    });




// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
jQuery(":input").focus(function(){      
   if (jQuery(this).hasClass("campuri-necesare") ) {
        jQuery(this).val("");
        jQuery(this).removeClass("campuri-necesare");
   }
});
});
```

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error?

Comment: The last condition `if (jQuery(":input").hasClass("campuri-necesare")) {
        return false;
    } ` is buggy because it tests whether the very first input element has the specified class, try `if (jQuery(".campuri-necesare:input").length) {
    return false;
} ` instead

Comment: Would you happen to be trying to use jQuery 2.x? For [IE 6 - 8 support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/), make sure you're using jQuery 1.x.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Thanks! I wasn't really relying on IE's debug console but now I've checked it and found the error. I had to add `var` before defining variables. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Frits Van Campen gave me a hint and I found the error. I had to add `var` text before defining every variable. Modern browsers are not seeing this thing as required, but the older ones ask for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DanCapitanDePlai

It seems there is some error in your javascript file

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addMethod' of undefined 
at adaugare_anunt.js on line number 291 Please fix that error first because usually in IE8 and earilier when the javascript encounters error none of the javascript will work.

Please use ie IE9 and press f12 change the browser mode to ie8 and start debugging.

Hope this helps you
Thankyou
Madhu Rakhal Magar